# Why do we use item'id or item'name as the key of react list item? I use the Array index as the key, it is more faster to rerender page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We use item'id or item'name as the key of item. but I find I use the index of Array as the key, it's more faster to rerender page. We always remind to use id or name as key, it's wrong?

I do two demos to compare, find the index is faster than a unique value that is id. we click the btn to call changeSort method to rerender page. You can find the id as key is slower

```py
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        sorts:  this.buildArr()
    }
}

buildArr = () => {
    let len = 10000, tempArr = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        tempArr.push({
            name: `a${i}`,
            id: `b${i}`
        })
    }
    return  tempArr;
}

changeSort = () => {
        this.setState((prestate) => ({
            sorts: prestate.sorts.reverse()
        }))
    }

render() {
    return (
     <div> 
         <div onClick={this.changeSort}>changeState</div>
        <ul>
           {this.state.sorts.map((item, index) => {  
               return <li key={index}>{item.name} </li>
            })}
        </ul>
     </div>
    )
}

compare with 

render() {
    return (
     <div> 
         <div onClick={this.changeSort}>changeState</div>
         <ul>
           {this.state.sorts.map((item, index) => {  
               return <li key={item.id}>{item.name} </li>
            })}
         </ul>
     </div>

    )
}
```

I expect that I use item'id as the key is more faster to rerender page than that I use Array index as the key, but it is be the opposite.

Comment: sorry, I use the click method  to change state to render page

Comment: sorry, I have changed my problem. I want to know we use item'id as the key is more slower to rerender page than we use the array index as the key . then we still use id as key, it's wrong? you can do a test

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of tracking shine when you only need to update a part of the collection. Say, one tile out of hundreds has changed. To know, which one has changed (and which one needs an update), some unique identifier is needed. Hence `key`.

Comment: sorry, I have changed my problem. I want to know we use item'id as  the key is more slower to rerender page than we use the array index as the key . then we still use id as key, it's wrong? you can do a test

Answer (score 0):

Think of each JSX as a DOM element. How do we create uniqueness in DOM is with tagging it with ID(unique). Same in this case. The Virtual DOM need an attribute to differentiate each unique element in react context we do so by using whats called Key. So, now we are assigning index as key. Lets think i used a splice or some mutation we expect the output to be some thing but we end up with a mis behavior. [Here is a good article to understand this](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). Here is one such [mis behavior example](https://jsbin.com/wohima/edit?output).

```
// noprotect
class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="col-xs-4 control-label">{this.props.name}</label>
        <div className="col-xs-8">
          <input type='text' className='form-control' />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {name: 'Foo1444610101010', id: 1444610101010},
        {name: 'Bar1444600000000', id: 1444600000000}
      ]
    };
  }

  userInput() {
    const firstItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.form-group:first-child input'));
    firstItems.forEach((item) => item.value = 'It is ' + (new Date()).toTimeString())

  }

  addItem() {
    const id = +new Date;
    this.setState({
      list: [ {name: 'Baz' + id, id} , ...this.state.list]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <b>How to use: </b>
        First write something in the inputs
        (or <a href='#' onClick={this.userInput}>simulate it</a>).
        Then hit <em>Add item</em> and see what happens…
        <hr/>
        <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}><b>Add item</b> to the beginning of the list</button>


        <h3>Dangerous <code>key=index</code></h3>
        <form className="form-horizontal">
            {this.state.list.map((todo, index) =>
              <Item {...todo}
              key={index} />
            )}
        </form>


        <h3>Better <code>key=id</code></h3>
        <form className="form-horizontal">
            {this.state.list.map((todo) =>
              <Item {...todo}
              key={todo.id} />
            )}
        </form>


        <hr/>
        <a href='https://medium.com/p/e0349aece318'>&laquo; Back to the article</a>.
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: sorry, I have changed my problem. I want to know we use item'id as the key is more slower to rerender page than we use the array index as the key . then we still use id as key, it's wrong? you can do a test

Comment: @huaLin There might be a misunderstanding the convention says the key should be anything unique, index is still unique until and unless you are doing a mutation. The design standard will never force you to use either id, name as key by creating an runtime error / breaking the source. It only recommends to keep the key unique.

Comment: You know index is also unique.  But it  dosen't recommend to  use index. I  wonder why not  recommend to use array index as the key?@karthik

Comment: @huaLin thats when i places one such misbehavior example in the answer. in both as index and as id fill all the four feilds and click on the add row above. You can see key as index add a row add a row to the bottum which is supposed to add it to the top

Comment: We can use array.prototype.unshift to add a row to the top.  It adds to top or bottom that we can solve. I think this isn't the reason for us not recommend to use array index as the key @ karthik

Comment: @huaLin array.prototype.unshift  might do the work but that example is made to explain the misbehavior.